# WP8 HTML5 Game Not Running Correctly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am placing my game into a HTML5 application in Visual Studio 2012 but it does not seem to run.  The background changes to the correct background color but the application does not continue past that.  There are no errors or anything though and when I test the game from the web on the phone in IE10 it runs perfectly with no errors.

Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Comment: You need to provide a bit more information with what's actually going on as well as some sample code.  Are you able to start up and run a basic HTML 5 application?  Is your game developed using HTML 5 only or is it actually Silverlight or some other type of plugin?  Are you debugging in a desktop browser, if so which one?

Comment: I have tested the application fully using the IE10 mobile browser on WP8. I have tested multiple HTML5 applications that work in the IE10 browser in WP8 but none seem to work when developing them into a HTML5 app in Visual Studio. It is just a straight HTML5 application.

Comment: I'm still not clear as to what you mean about the app not working in Visual Studio.  I'm assuming that you've created a new Web Application Project and copied some existing HTML5 app files into it.  And then you are having trouble using the app in the debugger (clicking play, pressing F5)?  When you are doing this, does the app actually start up in a desktop browser?  If so, **which one**?

Comment: I have created an HTML5 game in a separate program and engine. I am creating a Windows Phone HTML5 Application in Visual Studio. I then import my html5 project into the HTML folder in the application and set it to the index.html for the web browser element in the designer. When I test it in the windows phone emulator the html5 does not run.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this article](http://jessefreeman.com/articles/html5-on-windows-phone-8/) for a possible resolution to your problem.  Looks like there is a bug in the VS WP8 HTML5 project template where scripting is not enabled by default on the `WebBrowser` control.  Once you enable Javascript your application should start executing like you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have actually followed that exact article with no avail. I am wondering if it has something to do with offline access to the html5 javascript files.

Comment: Can you please post the code-behind for your MainPage.xaml.cs file?